# AlarmManager doesn't trigger a WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I'm trying to launch an intent service using an AlarmManager and a WakefulBroadcastReceiver. I can launch the service using `sendBroadcast()` and it works as it should, but I can't get it to launch with AlarmManager.

The code for launching it is like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Notifier.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);

    am.set(RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pi);
}
```

The `Notifier` class is like this:

```
public class Notifier extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.i("Notifier", "onReceive()");
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), NotifierService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    }
}
```

And the `NotifierService` is like this:

```
public class NotifierService extends IntentService
{
    private static final String TAG = "NotifService";

    public NotifierService()
    {
        super("NotifierService");
   }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "NotifierService: handling an intent");
    }
```

The manifest has these:

```
<service android:name=".NotifierService" />
<receiver android:name=".Notifier" />
```

Why doesn't the AlarmManager trigger the receiver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Notifier.class);
```

To:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, NotifierService .class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the `WAKE_LOCK` permission to your manifest, as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html)?

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(this, Notifier.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
//or repeate broadcaste per min use following
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pi);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: AlarmManager trigger the broadcast .

Comment: Having working code is great. Stackover, tho, is about learning. So it would be great if you could elaborate on WHY this works as well.